# How do you wish someone a happy saint's day in Quebec French?

Tags: expressions, québec

I'm a native French speaker, but I speak France French, and I need help with Québec French here. ^^
In France, you say "bonne fête" to someone when it's their saint's day on the calendar (which I think is a Catholic tradition). But in Québec, it seems like "bonne fête" is commonly used to wish people a happy birthday (whereas in France, "bon/joyeux anniversaire" is used instead). What do the Québécois say to people for their saint's day? 
Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: Puisque tu parles français, pourquoi ne pas poser ta question en français ??? Ce ne sont pas des anglophones qui risquent de te répondre !

Comment: Pouvez-vous brièvement expliquer comment ça marche, qu'est-ce qui détermine que pour telle personne, c'est tel saint qui correspond, puisque ce semble être un jour différent de son anniversaire de naissance. Par exemple, [aujourd'hui](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendrier_romain_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_(liturgie)#Novembre) ce serait _Saint André Dũng-Lạc et ses compagnons, martyrs_, comment savez-vous à qui souhaiter « bonne fête » aujourd'hui ?

Comment: @Gilles Je ne savais plus si on avait le droit, donc je suis partie du principe que non. Désolée ^^

Comment: @onvousaouï C'est vrai que c'est un peu compliqué. En général, on se fie au calendrier (celui du facteur, des pompiers, celui qu'on a dans notre agenda...) qui indique un saint par jour, sauf les jours de grandes fêtes comme Noël ou Pâques. La plupart de ces saints ont des prénoms qui sont courants en France (par exemple, sainte Catherine, le 25 novembre). On souhaite donc la fête aux gens qui portent ce prénom. Certains prénoms sont en double, par exemple, il y a deux saint Jean, un en juin (?) et un en décembre.

Comment: @onvousaouï À moins de savoir à quel saint Jean la personne se rattache (habitude des parents), on peut se tromper, mais ça n'a pas vraiment d'importance, parce qu'oublier la fête de quelqu'un n'est pas grave, sauf hors des familles qui en ont l'habitude, sinon beaucoup de gens n'ont pas cette tradition, donc c'est plutôt du "bonus" quand on y pense. Si un prénom n'apparaît pas tel quel sur le calendrier, on peut le "rattacher" à un prénom proche, par exemple un "Yann" aura sa fête sur une des deux saint Jean. Mais quand quelqu'un n'est pas de ta famille, difficile de deviner.

Comment: @onvousaouï Enfin, pour répondre à ta question, je viens de trouver ça http://nominis.cef.fr/contenus/saint/calendrier/simple/2017/11.html (affilié à l'Eglise catholique apparemment, vu qu'on parle de saints ça me semble approprié) qui indique saintes Flora et Marie pour le 24/11, donc c'est sans doute Flora qui apparaîtra sur le calendrier, ou les deux. Il y a un autre saint André le 30 novembre. Certains saints sont plus "importants" que d'autres (les plus anciens en général)... C'est vraiment un peu le fouillis, parce que ce sont des coutumes qui dépendent aussi des familles. =)

Comment: Merci pour toutes ces informations ! Je vous invite à éventuellement condenser le tout et à l'ajouter à votre réponse ! Les documents étaient difficiles à trouver sur Wikipédia et peuvent systématiser votre propos au besoin ([calendrier des saints en France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendrier_des_saints_en_France), l'ébauche [_fête du prénom_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_du_pr%C3%A9nom), ainsi que [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%AAte) qui réfère au _nom de baptême_). Il se peut que les noms de baptême au Québec variaient très peu (Joseph, Marie).J'ai déjà entendu/2

Comment: qqn. dire à qqn. d'autre _c'est la fête de [nom d'un saint], ton patron_, possiblement moins axé sur le prénom qu'un autre critère que j'ignore... ce serait qqc. d'assez inhabituel aujourd'hui sauf chez des gens assez pratiquant ou impliqués à cause du travail ou autrement, ou complètement inconnu comme tel comme le dit la réponse. C'est bien intéressant, merci !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La coutume de souhaiter "bonne fête" le jour du saint est inconnue au Québec. Il serait intéressant de savoir d'où vient l'utilisation de "bonne fête" pour souhaiter "bon anniversaire". Peut-être "bonne fête d'anniversaire"...

Comment: J'ai fini par poser la question directement à la personne dont c'était la fête, et elle m'a répondu la même chose. =) Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

Un Bonne Saints Jour? this is just my guess, as I am French Canadian who's dialect is from Louisiana, yet they are similar.

Comment: Ça me semble une expression ***très*** locale.

Comment: J'suppose. Au Louisiane, gens no celebrate l'Jour d'Saints